# Where to place presave functions?

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-nodes, drupal-preprocess

I need to manipulate a content type (people) before being saved from ADMIN.

I need to save the name + surname in the title

I know the presave functions (`hook_node_presave` or `hook_entity_presave`) should be used.

**My problem is where should these functions be written?**

I am writing them in themes / custom / MYPROJECT / MYPROJECT.theme but they do not run

Where are the preset functions written for ADMIN to use instead of the normal ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your hook in a .module file of a module. You should create a custom module for this, example below:

in `modules/custom` create a new folder `{PROJECT_NAME}_general` now referred to as MODULE_NAME) and add 2 files: `{MODULE_NAME}.info.yml` and `{MODULE_NAME}.module`

In the .info.yml file you just put some information regarding your custom module, for example:

```
name: Name of your module
type: module
description: Description of your custom module
core: 8.x
package: Custom
```

Now you can enable your module using either drush (`drush en MODULE_NAME -y`) or using "extend" from the admin menu.

Finally add your hook to the .module file and write the desired code.

You can also find all of this information [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules) and [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/understanding-hooks)

Hope this helps you out!